# Does adding cold water to evaporative air coolers actually produce colder air?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, cooling

Or should it be the other way around, because hotter water evaporates easier than cold water?

I know this sounds stupid, so just hear me out.

I use an evaporative cooler and add normal room temperature water. Someone told me to add cold water to get better results. I intuitively thought that indeed cold water will produce colder air.

But as we all know evaporative coolers cool air by using the air to evaporate water which takes away heat from the air. So, we need the water to evaporate to cool the air. But we know that hotter water evaporates easier than cold water.

So, should it not be the case that colder water will actually not evaporate as efficiently and hence not produce cooler air than in case of hotter water?

For what its worth, i tried both and could not feel any noticeable difference, but of course it was nowhere close to a controlled experiment. So, I would appreciate an answer about what does the physics predict about what would happen?

Comment: The energy change from the evaporation is much larger than from the warming up of the water. The temperature will make barely any difference so it's not worth cooling the water as you will be wasting energy to get this cold water.

Comment: But you are saying that the colder water will in theory produce more cooling, even if it is not considerable enough to be worth it, right ? But my point is, will it actually even produce less cooling, since it wont evaporate as much and hence will not be able to make use of energy change from the evaporation?

Comment: It will produce more cooling but increase the humidity in the room causing other problems.  As in, it does not work.

Comment: What does the air actually give up heat to? The evaporating water cools the remaining water. The water takes heat from the air *only if the air is warmer than the water*. The added heat raises the vapor pressure of the water until the heat of vaporization equals the heat given up by the air, and steady state is reached. Hot water won't cool the air until it has cooled down cooler than the air.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat "It will produce more cooling but increase the humidity in the room causing other problems" . I know it will increase humidity in the long run. My question is only about , when i put colder water in, will the exit air  have lower temperature or not

Comment: @PhilSweet The water takes heat from the air only if the air is warmer than the water "Is this really true?  Then, how do coolers  work with room temperature water. If it were true, then We would HAVE to add colder than room temperature water to get cool air . But, we know that is not the case, even adding room temperature water gives cool air. Or for that matter, how do room temperature water kept in the open ever evaporate, if they cannot absorb heat from the air, since both are at same temperature ?

Answer (score 2):

An evaporative cooler works by removing the suspended layer of saturated vapor from around the filter, encouraging it to use the ambient heat from the stream of the air thus making it colder, to evaporate to replace the washed-out moisture.

The latent heat for water is 2460 J/4.18 J per gram = 588.5 times more than specific heat. (Thanks To Phil Sweet for correcting me)

So the heat removed from the air is mostly done by water vaporization not by being near cold water.

Also, saturated water pressure increases with water temperature.

Bottom line just room temperature water is the most practical.

## Edit

there is new technolgy called two stage evaporative cooling. this technology is more efficient and can be used in humid climates as well. it doesn't add moisture to the conditioned air.

it is sold in US. i don't want to plug them, but you can search indirect evaporative cooler.

Comment: @Phil sweet, thanks Phil. i will correct my answer.

Comment: " _so the heat removed from the air is mostly done by water vaporization not by being near cold water._ " It is not about which process absorbs MOST heat, it is about which process absorbs heat QUICKEST . The latent heat vs specific heat addresses which would absorb most heat. Is there any similar figures which help figure out which absorbs heat most QUICKLY.

Comment: @silverrahul, of course, vaporization is faster. think about the contact area of a small body of water being in contact with the airflow absorbing its heat. Now compare it to the contact area of the same water atomized into vapor and peeled off the surface.?

Comment: I might make a tiny change: 'Bottom line is *whatever temperature* water is most easily available'

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Availability of water is not an issue. Any temperature water from freezing to boiling is easily available

Comment: @silverrahul  That was my point: don't waste time/energy changing the temperature of whatever water source you have on hand.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft My point is i have multiple temperatures of water on hand. Which one will be the best? Are you saying, there is no difference? Or are you saying there is negligible difference ? If it is negligible, then negligible in which direction ? Is room temp water negligibly better or refrigerated water negligibly better ?